# Shell Script - Check if XML tags match version

Tags: xml, shell, validation

I am quite new to shell scripting and need to make a script that checks xml tag within diferent xml files and diferent xml hierarchy and checks if version matches in different files.

But one extra step is I only need the version number within this tags, some tags may have more information (see examples - snapshot, release).

I am quite new to this, I have used this sed command to get the version, but can´t go much further than that....

Sucess and Fail Examples:

```
Hello, I am quite new to shell scripting and need to make a script that checks xml tag within diferent xml files and diferent xml hierarchy and checks if version matches in different files.
```

But one extra step is I only need the version number within this tags, some tags may have more information (see examples - snapshot, release).

I am quite new to this, I have used this sed command to get the version, but can´t go much further than that....

Sucess and Fail Examples:

Example 1 - Sucess

```
File1.xml
<project>
<version>1.2.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>

File2.xml
<project>
<parent>
<version>1.2.4</version>
</parent>
</project>

File3.xml
<project>
<parent>
<child>
<version>1.2.4-RELEASE</version>
</parent>
</child>
</parent>
</project>

OUTPUT - Versions Match - 1.0.4
```

Example 2 - Error

```
File1.xml
<project>
<version>1.2.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>

File2.xml
<project>
<parent>
<version>2.2.2</version>
</parent>
</project>

File3.xml
<project>
<parent>
<child>
<version>1.2.2-RELEASE</version>
</parent>
</child>
</parent>
</project>

OUTPUT - Version Mismatch - Check Version
```

Comment: Within each xml file, is there only one `<project>` element with only one `<version>` element child?

Comment: Hi @JackFleeting thanks for your reply. The version I want to compare is contained within the structure of each xml, but yes, there will be only 1 element of each.

Comment: @JackFleeting the XML structure will always be the same for each type of file (1,2,3), I dont need that t be dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with xml files, you should use a proper xml parser to read the file and xpath to search it.

As an aside, File3.xml (in both cases) is not well formed. So, for example, assuming this particular file content is:

```
<project>
  <parent>
     <child>
        <version>1.2.2-RELEASE</version>
     </child>
  </parent>
</project>
```

You can use, for example, either xmlstarlet:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "//project//version" -v . File3.xml
```

or xidel (which I personally prefer because of its support for xpath>1.0):

```
xidel File3.xml -e '//project//version'
```

In either case, the output should be

```
1.2.2-RELEASE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

VERSIONS=( $(cat file*.xml | grep -E "^<version>.*</version>$" | cut -d '>' -f 2 | cut -d '<' -f1 | cut -d '-' -f1) )
UNIQUE_VERSION=($(echo "${VERSIONS[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u))
if [ "${VERSIONS[0]}" == "${VERSIONS[1]}" ] && [ "${VERSIONS[1]}" == "${VERSIONS[2]}" ];
then
    echo "Versions are the same. $UNIQUE_VERSION"
    exit 0
else 
    echo "ERROR: Versions do not match. $UNIQUE_VERSION"
    exit 1
fi
```

`cat` the files (assuming there is a naming pattern and files are in the same directly)
Filter the version using `grep` and `cut`
Get the unique value only using `sort -u`
The output of the command is saved into an array `VERSIONS=( $(command) )`

Compare the values within the array and output message if they match or not including the unique version number.

Output when success:
`Versions are the same. 1.2.4`
Output when failure:
`ERROR: Versions do not match. 2.2.2`

Comment: Amazing thank you so much I will test it out today!!

Comment: You are welcome. I hope it works for you.  
By the way the else echo msg would print just one of the unique versions.. 
It works well if you have for example: `1.2.4-SNAPSHOT 2.2.2 1.2.4-RELEASE` it shows that `2.2.2` is the **odd one** 
but if all three are different it will print just the last version number, so you can remove `$UNIQUE_VERSION` from the else echo message if not matching your need.